# How to add two fragments together in a frameLayout in runtime

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-framelayout, navigation-drawer

I am developing an andorid application with `navigation drawer` and I have a layout for contentview like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="@color/default_color"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

So I can add  and replace fragment on navigation drawer item click. Everything okay till now.

But in one case, on clicking an item on navigation drawer I need to show two fragments instead of one ( just like a listFragment and details fragment ). How can I do it? Should I add two fragments into the framelayout then? But how? or should I change the contentView with different `drawerLayout` ? If yes, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just use nested fragments. Create another fragment that will dynamically create both your fragments and add them to its layout.

For more information read this: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

Comment: Thanks for your advice. What I have understand from your answer - I should have one fragment per navigation item like before. And one of them has two child fragment. Right? Also I know nested fragment doesn't support inflating from UI. So should I need to make those child fragment dynamically?

Comment: Well, I accepted your answer. But I am encountering a new problem and opened a thread here. Please take a review
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638834/app-crashes-when-i-navigate-second-time-to-nested-fragment

Comment: So the question is how do you use the two fragments for one activity for tablets and one fragment for each activity method using the navigation drawer?