# How to programmatically add two Fragments to a layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

i have trouble with attaching two fragments in one layout. I know how to add one fragment in a layout but I don't know how to put two fragments next to each other vertically in java android. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159982/how-do-i-add-a-fragment-to-an-activity-with-a-programmatically-created-content-v) adding one fragment is fully explained but there is no tutorial for putting two or more fragments in one layout.

Answer (score 2):

Create two `FrameLayout` in your xml file and place them the way you want. Add fragment in each of them.

Or see this [link for nested fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634178/how-to-add-two-fragments-together-in-a-framelayout-in-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
Fragment fragment = new MyAwsomeFragment();
            ft.add(R.id.linearLayoutActivity, fragment, null);//dont add to backstack
            ft.commit();
```

Here **R.id.linearLayoutActivity** points to a layout currently visible and inflated by the activity.